# Failed to load session "gnome" after system crash

Tags: gnome

Today my laptop suddenly crashed, and after restart, the log-in screen changed (it looked like unity), and when I tried to log-in, I received the following error: " failed to load session "gnome" ". I went to recovery menu, tried to repair broken packages and update grub bootloader. It did not help. Now I have the same screen, but when I try to login, it says that I successfully logged in, but the log-in screen does not disappear and I can't do anything further.

Does anyone have any ideea what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Do not restart. This could effectively leave your system without GUI.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This will install all the missing GNOME dependencies.

Comment: why not use the "sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop" command instead?